# Regex Matches only getting count 1 instead of 2

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

This is my Regex:

```
private static Regex _errorRegex = new Regex(" <div class=\"styleRed\">(?<message>.*?)</div>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

and the webpage has data like:

```
<div class="styleRed">• Zero is required in the Consideration Field for Deed Type CEDOT (Row 1). </div><div class="styleRed">• Zero is required in the Assume/Value Field for Deed Type CEDOT (Row 1). </div>


var matches = _errorRegex.Matches(webpage);
```

the matches count is always 1. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: This calls for a link to my favorite SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/860585

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you post enough of the webpage to show that it should match twice?

Comment: @dlf: Basically I am trying to find all text inside *<div class="styleRed">blah blah </div>* within all occurences.

Comment: Have you looked at what it is actually matching?  The `.*` is probably being greedy and matching everything until the last `</div>`.

Comment: @juharr, nope, he is already using the non-greedy version (`.*?`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex pattern starts with a space.

In your example, the second `div` on the HTML page doesn't have a space before it.

Hence, it doesn't match.